# How to make eventReactive or observeEvent for ggplot?

Tags: r

I want to refresh the ggplot by click on action button. I have tried to use both: eventReactive and observeEvent and it doesn't work.

```
rm(server)
rm(map3)


ui <- fluidPage(

  actionButton("button","button"),
  plotOutput("rys")
)


server <- function(input, output){

  map3 <- eventReactive(input$button,{
    ggplot(data.frame(a=runif(10)*10,b=runif(10)*10),aes(a,b))+geom_point()
  })

  output$rys <- renderPlot({ 
    map3
    })
}



shinyApp(ui=ui, server=server)
```

Please help me I'm coding in R for 5 hours and I'm so tired and have a lot of work through this night :(

Answer (score 2):

Since you really just seem to be changing your data when the button is clicked, how about structuring your app like this

```
library(shiny)
library(ggplot2)

ui <- fluidPage(

  actionButton("button","button"),
  plotOutput("rys")
)

server <- function(input, output){
 mydata  <- eventReactive(input$button,{
    data.frame(a=runif(10)*10, b=runif(10)*10)   
  })

  output$rys <- renderPlot({ 
    if(!is.null(mydata())) {
      ggplot(mydata(), aes(a,b))+geom_point()
    }
  })
}

shinyApp(ui=ui, server=server)
```

Here `mydata` is a reactive data.frame that updates each time the button is clicked. Then use use the updated data to draw the plot in the `renderPlot` call.

Your code also would have worked if you had just used

```
 output$rys <- renderPlot({ 
    map3()
 })
```

You need to use `()` to get at the value of reactive objects.

Comment: maaaan, really thx for dat () ! I forgot about this. Wish ya go to Heaven.